# Change keyboard language in debian server?

Tags: debian

I need print this symbol because in my vps i can't write the following symbole (@).
The problem is that the keyboard that i'm using in vps doesnt include this symbole.
How can i change the language or include the symbol easily?
I don have gui in my case only console.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`

Answer (score 3):

You can change language by calling:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

or by editing `/etc/default/keyboard` (additional info about parameters in `man 5 keyboard`).

After you should restart keyboard service:

```
systemctl restart keyboard-setup.service
```

Comment: thank u for your answer so much. but i will ask you maybe know. i tried to follow the steps, however in my vps didnt work. I was trying put this symbol @ in my vps. The vps is cloudsigma and the link is: https://zrh.cloudsigma.com/ui/#/ maybe you know why i can't use correctly the at(@) symbol in my vps?

Comment: What error did you get when you entered the different commands? Without the errors, it's a guessing game!

Comment: i ask with this account. I changed the language but i can not put this symbol (@) never. could you recommend or check it since the website? maybe you know the reason.

Comment: great answer thanks!!